# virtual function in base class

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, derived-class

Let's say I have a base class of shapes *shape* and two derived classes *square* and *circle*.
Now I would like to have a function where the shape is not specified

```
double foo(shape S)
{
return getArea;
}
```

but which prints the area of a square when calling

```
square sq();
foo(sq);
```

and the area of a circle when calling

```
circle cr();
foo(cr);
```

Thus, I declared a **virtual function** in the base class (returning only 0) and the appropriate virtual functions in the two derived classes.
However, when calling *foo* with either a square or circle object I always get the result of the base class. How to do it properly?

---

EDIT:

Now the code is working, here a simple example. The solution is indeed to pass the object from the *shape* class (derived or not) by **reference**. This allows to define a generic function which accepts all kind of derived objects:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class shape
{
public:
  shape (double L_par): L(L_par){};
  double getL(){return L;}
  virtual double getArea(){return 0;}

private:
    const double L;
}; 
class square: public shape
{
public:
  square (double L_par): shape(L_par),area(L_par*L_par){cout<<"square with area="<<area<<endl;};
   virtual double getArea(){return area;}

private:
    const double area;
};
class circle: public shape
{
public:
  circle (double L_par): shape(L_par),area(3.1415*L_par*L_par){cout<<"circle with area="<<area<<endl;};
  virtual double getArea(){return area;}

private:
const double area;
};

void foo(shape &shp)
{
  cout<<"L="<<shp.getL()<<endl;
  cout<<"area="<<shp.getArea()<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  double L=4;
  square sq1(L);
  circle cr1(L);

  foo(sq1);
  foo(cr1);
  cout<<sq1.getArea()<<endl;
  cout<<cr1.getArea()<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post ALL of your code...

Comment: I'd guess you are a victim of [object-slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c/274634#274634), can't tell for sure from what you're posting as sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the `shape` by value:

```
double foo(shape S) { .... }
```

This means the function has a copy of only the `shape` part of the object. This is called [*object slicing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).  You can fix this by passing a reference:

```
double foo(const shape& S) { .... }
```

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic binding through C++ is implemented using references and pointers. Therefore your function `foo` should take a reference to shape;

```
double foo(shape &s) {
    return s.getArea(); //your virtual function?
}
```